# Is "I like ice-cream either" correct?

Tags: word-meaning

My daughter returned from school yesterday and told me their teacher went through some of their writing and discussed good ways to use English language. So he came up with "I like ice-cream either" and suggested it should be used instead of "I like ice-cream too" or "I also like ice-cream". And the contrary should be "I like ice-cream neither".

Ok, I think there is the fine-detail of whether you're having a discussion with John, Paul and Mary about the emotions re. ice-cream - or if you're discussing ice-cream vs. fruit, cake and chocolate, but leaving that apart...my gut-feeling is that this phrase is plain wrong.

Can someone rescue the teacher's point of view and show/explain similar valid use of "either"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid, the teacher is *not correct!* Why? Because, 'I like ice cream either' -I'm not sure whether natives approve this.

It depends whether you want to use it informally or formally. Short answers are informal (Me too, Me either...etc); long answers (I like ice cream too) look formal.

Okay, the question is what to use: 'either' or 'too.'

The simple rule that I remember is *if the sentence is positive* and you agree, you use '**too**.' On the other hand, *if the sentence is negative,* you use '**either**.'

Examples: informal

> I *like* ice cream ~ Me too! 
>   I *don't like* ice cream ~ Me either!

Formal:

> I *don't have money* ~ I *don't either!* 
>  I *have* money ~ I *do too!*

[Brits may prefer saying *I haven't either* and *I have too!*]

Comment: Good answer - although I use "Me neither" as the informal form (your second informal example), but I know some people use "Me either".  ("Neither do I" and "Nor do I" are other possible, relatively formal responses.)

Answer (score 2):

The teacher is wrong here because *either* is a negative polarity term when used in the context you describe. Or more precisely:

> *Either* can be licensed by many of the standard NPI triggers: negation (*not*), certain downward entailing determiners (*no, few*), adverbs (*scarcely, hardly, seldom, rarely*) (Klima 1964), verbs and adjectives (*doubt, cease, refuse, unlikely*) (Green 1973).
>   [- Holtze Rullmann, *Either* as a Negative Polarity Item](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiL56j05o_WAhXMi5QKHXWKAykQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.bu.edu%2Fbfraser%2FOther%2520Specific%2520DMs%2520or%2520DPs%2520Papers%2FRullman%2520-%2520either%2520as%2520a%2520Negative%2520Polarity%2520Item.doc&usg=AFQjCNE3dQq8RTWcJZ8iT5koqwNJJbfcPw)

The link goes into more detail about the nuances of how the negative polarity term *either* is used. It's worth reading in its entirety.